# Color space and print quality

Tags: printing, printer, colors

I've created a set of diagrams in HTML that are meant to be printed using common inkjet printers. Will I get better print quality if I convert colors from sRGB to CMYK first, or stick with CMYK primaries to begin with? Will the edges and lines and text appear sharper? Right now when I print the diagrams they look a little muddled and blurry.

Here is an example diagram:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vega_strike_key_bindings_chart.svg

Thanks!

Comment: A diagram like that isn't really affected by the color space.  If the output isn't sharp, it's because of the paper you're using, the print quality setting, and the capability of the printer.  As a starting point for comparing, set the print quality to the highest setting and use photo paper.  Also verify that the image contains enough resolution (printing at ~300 dpi of native image resolution should be sharp, but a 100 dpi screenshot printed at original size won't be).

Comment: Okay. I was hoping that using CMYK colors would have some sort of sub-pixel effect.

Comment: No, the color space doesn't affect that.  There are different mathematical ways to express a given color.  Different color spaces have slightly different limits on the "extreme" colors that can be represented.  Within those limits, the colors are the same.  Sub-pixel rendering can make edges smoother by making them less sharp (not more sharp), and that isn't done using extreme colors.